# HERE Geocode Autocomplete no Unit/Apt No

Tags: here-api

I am not getting the Unit Number in response structure as mentioned in the API Documentation,

"For addresses from Australia, New Zealand and Canada a unit number can be included in the result if it was part of the query."

I am using autocomplete geocoder for NZ.

I tried to change the requestType but no help. API is not so clear on how to request Unit Number.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Actually, when we type the unit/housenumber in the query it actully brings the Unit number.